How to test for improvement of low vs high scores
I have paired scores (continuous variable) from time 0 and time 1. I would like to find out if: the intervention between time 0 and 1 was more beneficial to poor performing participants than to others.
On a scatter plot, the angle of the line from a linear model looks as if poor scores improved more than others. But this makes sense any way as high scores from time 0 have less room to go up, as they are already closer to the maximum score, whereas low scores have plenty of room to go up and not a lot to go down.
EDIT: This is a language test with scores between 0 and 100.
How should I approach this problem?

That's why you are doing a paired test, which takes into account that these observations are coming from the same individual, and so the scores are likely to be (more) similar. What is this score and how is it defined? Is it bounded between some values?

I added some detail. I guess I could phrase this question as "did people in the lower quartile improve more than people from the upper quartile" or something like that. Or in other words, I expect scores from high performing individuals to be similar, and scores of low performing individuals to be different (better).

"But, this makes sense anyway as high scores from time 0 have less room to go up, as they are already closer to the maximum score." This is a valid observation (it may depend on the specific test how much of an issue this is). The problem with this is that it implies that it is not possible to tell apart from the data alone whether stronger improvement from lower scores is because the intervention helps more there, or because it's generally harder to improve if your score is already high.

Essentially it may be that improving is generally harder from higher scores, and this would imply that the amount of improvement from higher scores vs. from lower scores is not directly comparable. Do you have data with no intervention or "placebo intervention" between 0 and 1 with which you can compare what happens if the intervention takes place? (I haven't thought through how exactly this could be used to address your question, but it may help.)

What is now often called a slope graph (Edward Tufte's term, but an older and more widespread idea) may be helpful. Plot each person as a linear segment for score on $y$ axis and time on $x$ axis. Even if it is a tangled mess, it will make vivid that the pattern is not as simple as you thought,  Examples and references at https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/epdf/10.1177/1536867X0900900408

@ChristianHennig Good idea, but no I don't have a placebo group. Perhaps of interest is that the distribution of scores is skewed as most people have high scores. This may matter as well though not sure exactly in what way.

@NickCox this looks helpful, thanks for the link! Will get back when I had the chance to give it a proper read.

If most people get high scores, a square or cube scale for plotting would stretch high  points apart relatively (and either scale is entirely compatible with zeros if they occur). Note the interaction with your and @ChristianHennig's point, so that say improvement from 85 to 95 may be much harder work than say improvement from 5 to 15.  Exponential scale (antilog) is also possible.

How many people? Can you post (some or all of) the data?

@NickCox writes "Note the interaction with your and ChristianHennig's point, so that say improvement from 85 to 95 may be much harder work than say improvement from 5 to 15." The problem is that if this is so, essentially it may not be possible to address the question you have with the available data (unless the level goes down or stays constant in one of the groups), without making untestable assumptions about how changes in lower and higher regions of the scale actually compare (placebo data may address that to some extent).

I have often used the slope graph that Nick suggests. It can be very illuminating. It may not be possible to do a good statistical test, that depends on how bad the ceiling effect is. One thing: I would not divide scores into quartiles.

How reliable and accurate are the scores? Is there a lot of measurement error? If there is, then two time points may not be enough.

I agree with @PeterFlom if Peter's point is that binning may well be at best a distraction here and at worst arbitrary and confusing.  Frank Harrell has much to say on this. Again, references at https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1801800311 esp. Section 1.

I agree with @ChristianHennig except that I want to add a positive twist: part of the interest of this question is identifying the scale or scales s on which comparison is best made, just as there are many other contexts in which logarithmic scale for example is a good idea. I know that Peter Flom has an aversion, not to say a mild phobia, to working with transformed scales, but when they work well, they are white magic.
